# Realtek and USB Wi-Fi Adapters not Found in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, realtek

Folks,

I have a Lenovo Legion Y7000 with dual boot system (Win10 and Ubuntu 18.04). The internal wireless card is Realtek 8822be and I have also attached a Panda wireless USB drive (as I was unable to get the internal wireless card working). When I go to Wi-Fi Settings in Ubuntu, I see "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" for both internal and USB Wi-Fi drives. But the following commands actually show that Ubuntu has detected my Wi-Fi chips:

```
o-vh@o-vh:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:7070 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b023 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:5372 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5372 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Also,

```
o-vh@o-vh:~$ iwconfig
wlp7s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

enp8s0    no wireless extensions.

wlx7cdd90764d5b  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

which is not clear to me, as it seems that two wireless cards are detected, but I still see two `no wireless extensions.` messages. Finally, when I run `lshw -C network`, I see:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 00
       serial: 48:5f:99:b2:fd:e7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8822be driverversion=4.15.0-50-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:143 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4300000-a430ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 15
       serial: e8:6a:64:c1:75:66
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.88.187 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4204000-a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: wlx7cdd90764d5b
       serial: 7c:dd:90:76:4d:5b
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=4.15.0-50-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Note that for the USB Wi-Fi I see `*-network DISABLED` while I don't see this for the Realtek Wi-Fi.

Can anyone give me some hints on what the problem is and how I can fixed the "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" issue? I appreciate your help very much!

I have tried many of the approaches suggested for similar (but not identical) problems without any success.

Comment: I would love to troubleshoot one or the other but not both at the same time. Please detach the USB and then run: `rfkill list all` and also: `dmesg | grep -e r88 -e wlp` and also: `sudo iwlist scan` Next, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi chili555, thanks for offering me help. I removed the USB wireless card and ran the commands you suggested while only having the internal wireless card. Please see the results for executing the commands in the following: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rhcPq9FgBr/

Comment: Please check for the solution in the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, the link provided related to the duplicate question resolved my issue!

Comment: Awesome! I suggest that you give @Pilot6 an upvote at the duplicate. It shows others that the solution works.